# Bootstrap 3.1.1 Carousel not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Xcart, PHP5.6, Bootstrap 3.1.1

My goal is to make a carousel that displays 3 items at a time and loops over a total of 5 items.

I've ensured my libraries are being called and that they are where they're supposed to be however the carousel never initiates.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
       .container{
         margin: 0 auto;
       } 
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div id="this-carousel-id" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihiQ2.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihiQ2.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihiQ2.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihiQ2.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihiQ2.png" />
      </div>
   </div>
   <a class="carousel-control left" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;<    /a>     
   <a class="carousel-control right" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;    </a>  
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel').carousel({
           interval: 4000
  });
});
```

I've tried using sample code from the docs to get *something* to display carousel-like behavior but instead they are stacking:

[image]
[image]
[image]
I feel terrible because this question has been asked repeatedly and I've followed the answers but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the snippet you're showing, you have to put your javascript into `<script>...</script>` tags, be sure that your cdns are using `https` and not `http`.

You also forgot to add `bootstrap.min.css`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: ... I am an idiot. Thank you very much for pointing this out to me!

Answer (score 1):

> Use the `https://...` instead of the `http://...`

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Comment: I've updated this but it was @Hijikata Amamyia 's answer that made the carousel work. Thank you for telling me this!